# Mac OS Mavericks - SSH into El Capitan - VIM cursor color

Tags: macos, vim, ssh, osx-mavericks, osx-elcapitan

I'm running Mavericks and opening a terminal connection to an El Capitan machine. Both fully updated. I am running vim that comes with Mac OS (vim 7.3) on the El Capitan machine. I am trying to change the cursor color, but I can't. It seems that Terminal is controlling the cursor color and making it gray. I would prefer the VIM behavior of inverting the foreground and background on a highlighted letter. If I go to Terminal Preferences, I can change the cursor color to something else, but I can't get it to invert ever.

I have tried to using highlight Cursor lCursor CursorLine CursorColumn... It seems that whatever I do, the cursor color is controlled solely by the Terminal application.

I checked the Terminal settings for "Declare terminal as," and it is set to 
xterm-256color. Is there some setting to change, or a switch for the ssh command? This is only a problem when SSHing into another machine. Running vim locally works fine.

Please help!
Nachum

Comment: You can't change the cursor style.

Comment: That sucks. Another note is that I believe I was testing using MacVim on my local system... (dumb mistake). So it seems that vim is problematic whether or not I'm using SSH.